# PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP not generating src and header files

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

My cmake configuration is not generating any protobuf src and header files.
I've already checked if the proto files can be found.

```
Cmakelists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
..
include(FindProtobuf REQUIRED)
file(GLOB PROTO_DEF "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuf/*/*.proto")

foreach(file ${PROTO_DEF})    
    if(EXISTS ${file})
        MESSAGE("YES")
    else()
        MESSAGE("NO")
    endif()
endforeach()
SET(PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP_APPEND_PATH PROTOBUF)
SET(PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE protoc.exe)

..
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRC PROTO_INCL ${PROTO_DEF})
..
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${INCLUDES} ${INTERNAL_INCLUDES} ${SRC} ${PROTO_SRC} ${PROTO_INCL})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

I have checked the FindProtobuf.cmake and half way through:

```
foreach(FIL ${ARGN})
    get_filename_component(ABS_FIL ${FIL} ABSOLUTE)
    get_filename_component(FIL_WE ${FIL} NAME_WE)

    list(APPEND ${SRCS} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FIL_WE}.pb.cc")
    list(APPEND ${HDRS} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FIL_WE}.pb.h")
    
    MESSAGE(1 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
    MESSAGE(2 ${_protobuf_include_path})
    MESSAGE(3 ${ABS_FIL})
    MESSAGE(4 ${PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE})
    
    add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FIL_WE}.pb.cc"
             "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FIL_WE}.pb.h"
      COMMAND  ${PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE}
      ARGS --cpp_out  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${_protobuf_include_path} ${ABS_FIL}
      DEPENDS ${ABS_FIL}
      COMMENT "Running C++ protocol buffer compiler on ${FIL}"
      VERBATIM )
      
  endforeach()
```

You can see i've added the 4 message commands, the script reaches this point and variables show good values.
The proto files do have a depencency to the library, thus the command should get executed !?

Any ideas on this problem?

## update

replacing the add_custom_command with

```
EXEC_PROGRAM(${PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE} ARGS --cpp_out ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${_protobuf_include_path} ${ABS_FIL}
```

does generate the source and header files, must i manually activate the custom_commmands?

Regards Auke

Answer (score 3):

The add_custom_command is fired (for my project) during compilation time.
Adding

```
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${PROTO_SRC} ${PROTO_INCL} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
```

gives cmake info that the files will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative if you have an external proto folder:

```
file(GLOB PROTOBUF_FILELIST ${PROTO_INCLUDE_DIR}/*.proto)
foreach( proto_file ${PROTOBUF_FILELIST} )
   get_filename_component(proto_name ${proto_file} NAME_WE)
   get_filename_component(proto_path ${PROTO_INCLUDE_DIR} ABSOLUTE)
   set_source_files_properties("${proto_path}/${proto_name}.pb.cc"
                               "${proto_path}/${proto_name}.pb.h"
                               PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
endforeach()
```

Comment: I don't suppose you can point me to a complete cmake file where there are multiple proto files and one imports another?

Answer (score 0):

This problem only happens when the target is a library (using add_library, add_executable seems to be fine). The PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP will defer the generation of protobuf sources and headers when building the library. A workaround is to define a custom target and add it as a dependency to the lib target. e.g.

```
add_custom_target(proto_dep DEPENDS ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${OTHER_SRCS})
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} proto_dep)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE gRPC::grpc++ gRPC::grpc++_reflection protobuf::libprotobuf)
```

Comment: How do you get the list of `*.grpc.pb.cc files`? I only have the list of `*.pb.cpp` files to compile contained in the variable `${PROTO_SRCS}. In your example, you aren't compiling either list, no?

Comment: this doesn't work, don't waste time on this. I tired still can not generate cpp

Answer (score -1):

See that:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/module/FindProtobuf.html

Example:

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS foo.proto)
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS EXPORT_MACRO DLL_EXPORT foo.proto)
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS DESCRIPTORS PROTO_DESCS foo.proto)
protobuf_generate_python(PROTO_PY foo.proto)
add_executable(bar bar.cc ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
target_link_libraries(bar ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES})
```

**Note** The protobuf_generate_cpp and protobuf_generate_python functions and add_executable() or add_library() calls only work properly within the same directory.